# Grouping in cognos

Tags: report, cognos

I want to create a grouping and then print sum as per the design

[Cognos report mock picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8RBO.png)

I am able to do grouping of first two columns(when groups are present) but for totals column. I am unable to perform. Can anyone tell me the steps to group and display the output as the picture

Comment: Which version of Cognos are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Select the column you want to summarize and click the Sum -> Total option.  This will create a total row for each group you have, and a single overall total at the bottom. You can delete any subtotal lines you do not want.  If you click the Unlock button, you can edit the titles within the totals row.